# O nome do membro viril em bom vernáculo (sim, esse mesmo) já foi aceitável? Quando passou a ser tabu?

Tags: etimologia, uso-de-palavras, mudanças-históricas

Encontra-se no passado a palavra *caralho* usada em situações em que hoje causaria escândalo. No [Corpo Informatizado do Português Medieval](http://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/) encontramo-la em três cantigas de escárnio e maldizer dos séculos XIII e XIV. Eis um exemplo atribuído a [Pero Garcia Burgalês (Wikiédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pero_Garcia_Burgal%C3%AAs), com itálico meu em todas as citações:

> Maria Negra [é] desventuirada!
>   E porque quer tantas pissas comprar,
>   pois lhe na mãã nom querem durar
>   e lh’assi morrem aa malfada[da]?
>   ((V5)) E num *caralho* grande que comprou,
>   onte ao serão o esfolou,
>   e outra pissa tem já amormada.

As cantigas de escárnio e maldizer usam uma linguagem mais colorida que a encontramos noutros textos da época. Mas que dizer deste texto, de caráter científico, identificado no [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/) como o *Códice de Valentim Fernandes* de 1506 – 10:

> Os negros fazem hûu arpam e ho untam com herva peçonhenta / atado bem em hûa asta pesada / E o negro que ja sabe per onde ha de vijr o aliffante / esta sobre hûa aruore e leixa cayr o dito arpam ao aliffante quando passam muytos juntos / Emtam o negro lhe segue hûa legoa ou duas // ou mais ata onde vaa a morrer / E se vaa ter a outra jurdiçam tornam lhe o aliffante ou pagam lhe ou põem lhe guerra por ysso / E comem no Ho melhor comer delle he as unhas e a tromba e ho *caralho* sobre todo

Então a questão é: estes exemplos são aberrações, ou *caralho* era mesmo uma palavra que era normalmente usada quando se queria referir o dito cujo? Se era uma palavra aceitável, quando é que o deixou de o ser?

Comment: Esta pergunta recebeu um voto negativo. Seria útil que quem o deu apresentasse as suas razões. Se foi por causa do palavrão, esclareço que a pergunta segue as recomendações de boa prática relativamente a palavrões [(ver esta discussão no meta)](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/196/full-clarity-or-political-correctness): mencionar a palavra onde for necessário no corpo da pergunta, mas não a incluir no título.

Comment: A história que eu conhecia era que [caralho era utilizado para designar o cesto no mastro das caravelas](https://www.google.com/search?q=caralho+mastro). Existem várias páginas na interne a confirmar, mas ao que parece não passa de um mito urbano que nasceu na internet, segundo a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caralho) que têm uma história etimológica bastante mais completa.

Comment: @Duarte Também ouvi essa, e que viria daí a expressão *vai para o c.* Mas já se usava na poesia medieval, e o cognato espanhol sugere uma origem ainda mais antiga.

Comment: Fiquei confuso. Então a palavra que se tornou impropério não era para definir o posto que ficava no topo dos mastros das embarcações? Julgo que a associação ao pénis, foi sempre metafórica.

Comment: @joao tudo o que posso dizer é que todos os exemplos antigos que vi se referem ao pénis, não a mastros.

Comment: @Jacinto, de acordo com [esta fonte](http://www.docspt.com/index.php?topic=4704.0), é referido que de acordo com _a Academia Portuguesa de Letras, "CARALHO" é a palavra com que se denominava a pequena cesta que se encontrava no alto dos mastros das caravelas, de onde os vigias prescrutavam o horizonte em busca de sinais de terra_. Daí a expressão "vai para o caralho", que significava ir para esse lugar, que era pouco desagradável nas embarcações-

Comment: @joao_pimentel, vê se consegues localizar a fonte original; lançaria alguma luz sobre esta questão. Infelizmente essa fonte é muito vaga: não nos dá título ou data de publicação, nem nome de autor.

Comment: Porquê de o cesto da gávea ser o lugar mais desagradável da embarcação: por ser o ponto mais afastado do centro de gravidade da embarcação, é o ponto que mais oscila durante a navegação, o que induz enjoo muito mais fortemente que em qualquer outro lugar no navio.

Comment: @Marcelo, sim, mas até agora ainda não vi um exemplo sequer de *caralho* usado para designar o cesto da gávea. O que não há dúvida é que há perto do cesto da gávea uma peça chamada *verga*...

Comment: @Jacinto, será que _verge_ do Francês saiu daí?

Comment: @Marcelo, origem comum: vêm ambos do latim *virga* 'ramo delgado e flexível, bastão' e já também 'pénis'; se esta aceção se manteve do latim até ao francês e português modernos ou se foi reiventada (a metáfora é simples) é que eu não sei. Vê [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/verge) e [dicionário de latim](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=virga&la=la&can=virga0#lexicon).

Comment: Várias fontes na internet ([como essa](http://etimologias.dechile.net/PIE/?gher-3)), dizem que o castelhano "carajo" (e o português "caralho) veem do latim "characulum", que significa pau/estaca, tendo portanto o desenvolvimento etimológico igual ao das palavras "pau" e "cacete", i.e., originou-se como denotando um objeto faliforme para então denotar o membro viril. A outra origem possível é a de que "caralho" venha do latim "carassus", relativa ao mastro dos navios.

Comment: Quanto ao uso aceitável de palavras que referem-se ao membro viril, só notei um caso: quando a palavra também possui um sentido não-vulgar. Meu avô usa o termo "cacete" de forma não chula, para se referir a um bastão. Devido à idade, ele já usa uma bengala para andar, e a chama de "cacete". Segundo ele, nunca ouviu tal palavra como sendo vulgar durante sua juventude, mas como um sinônimo de bastão, pau, bengala, etc.

Comment: Porque motivo o texto científico tem `/`? É poesia ou ciência?

Comment: @Seninha diria que por motivos psicanalíticos, é muito plausível que objetos com características fálicas, tenham por conseguinte sido utilizados para, num contexto comparativo e metafórico, definir o membro sexual masculino. Se observardes com minúcia esta [lista](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/sinonimos/p%C3%AAnis/) de impropérios e sinónimos para definir no calão, o referido membro sexual, vereis que todos ou quase todos os objetos mencionados, têm uma estrutura faliforme ou cilíndrica. Por isso, considero muito plausível a origem etimológica associada a pau/estaca ou mastro.

Comment: @João, aparece com "/" na trancrição do Corpus do Português; imagino que indique o fim de linha no texto de origem.

Comment: @Jacinto e com linhas tão curtas, não será mais um texto literário e menos científico? Apenas uma pergunta.

Comment: Mas qual é a questão em concreto? Quer saber em que época passou a ser considerada uma palavra obscena?

Comment: @Carlos, exato; ou se já era na idade média, e os exemplos são aberrações.

Answer (score 1):

Caro Jacinto, não respondendo diretamente à sua questão, mas não tendo espaço nos comentários para alongar, devo referir que a utilização de impropérios nas cantigas de escárnio e mal-dizer sempre foi aceitável, e tal está devidamente registado. Logo, pelo facto de *caralho* aparecer numa dessas cantigas que cita, julgo que tal não viabiliza *per se* a tese de que o vocábulo seria aceitável, ou pelo menos dito, no quotidiano.

Martim Soares, trovador português, documentado no período compreendido entre 1220 e 1260, escreve este poema em espécie de escárnio, a um tal Pero Rodrigues.

```
Pero Rodrigues, da vossa mulher,
não acrediteis no mal que vos digam.
Tenho eu a certeza que muito vos quer.
Quem tal não disser quer fazer intriga.
Sabei que outro dia quando eu a fodia,
enquanto gozava, pelo que dizia,
muito me mostrava que era vossa amiga.

Se vos deu o céu mulher tão leal,
que vos não agaste qualquer picardia,
pois mente quem dela vos for dizer mal.
Sabei que lhe ouvi jurar outro dia
que vos estimava mais do que a ninguém;
e para mostrar quanto vos quer bem,
fodendo comigo assim me dizia.
```

Ademais, não desprestigiando a fonte mencionada, parece-me que o Códice de Valentim Fernandes carece de carácter científico, na medida que tem várias linhas, sendo o tipo de textos mais vocacionados para a literatura poética, mas posso estar errado, e corrija-me se assim o for. Tomei a liberdade de o reescrever em conformidade com a mudança de linhas

```
Os negros fazem hûu arpam e ho untam com herva peçonhenta
atado bem em hûa asta pesada
E o negro que ja sabe per onde ha de vijr o aliffante
esta sobre hûa aruore e leixa cayr o dito arpam ao aliffante quando passam muytos juntos
Emtam o negro lhe segue hûa legoa ou duas

ou mais ata onde vaa a morrer
E se vaa ter a outra jurdiçam tornam lhe o aliffante ou pagam lhe ou põem lhe guerra por ysso
E comem no Ho melhor comer delle he as unhas e a tromba e ho caralho sobre todo
```

Comment: Estou de acordo com o que dizes. Caráter "científico" foi a forma inexata que me veio à cabeça na altura; o que eu quero dizer, mais rigorosamente, é que é um texto "sério"; não é satírico ou cómico, como as cantigas de escárnio e mal-dizer. Eu não dou importância às barras (usadas habitualmente para separar versos). O texto é claramente de natureza descritiva e factual.

Answer (score 0):

"Caralho" realmente era designação à cestinha que ficava no alto do mastro dos navios, segundo a [Super Interessante](http://super.abril.com.br/ciencia/a-ciencia-do-palavrao/). Indo para a [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caralho), encontramos que isso começou a ser um tabu aproximadamente pelo século XIII.

Comment: Na Wikipédia diz que se tornou tabu a partir da contrarreforma, que é sXVI, não sXIII.  O artigo da Super Interessante é muito interessante, e se *caralho* já designou o cesto da gávea é até potencialmente relevante para esta questão, mas eu nunca vi ninguém comprovar esse uso de *caralho*. Eles também dizem que *coitado* é  “aquele que sofreu o coito”, e isto não está de acordo com o Houaiss. Parece-me que eles não verificaram bem algumas coisas.